# what is wrong with this print_repeat function?

Tags: c

print_repeat should print out the string s, but repeat the ith character i times (starting counting at 1).
So print_repeat("this") should print thhiiissss

```
int print_repeat(char s[]){
    int i,j;

     i = 0;
     while (s[i] != '\0');{
         for (j = 1; j <= i+1; j+1){
             putchar(s[i]);
         }
    }
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    print_repeat("this");
}
```

Comment: This is `star_vowels`. Where is `print_repeat`?

Comment: I second KennyTM's nod, but I mostly want to point out - please don't use `void main()`. It's not standard conforming.

Comment: sorry, grabbed the wrong code

Comment: `void main()` is probably the first thing you should fix

Comment: If you use `for` keyword for cycles with counter, you should avoid error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the correct code below:

```
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    { 
      for (j = 1; j <= i+1; j++)
      { 
        putchar(s[i]); 
      } 
     i++;
   }
```

The main problems were:
1. Not incrementing the variable i inside while loop
2. Variable j is not incremented correctly
3. There is semicolon right after the while which is incorrect.

Suggestion: try debugging your code. That will help you learn faster.

Comment: why not initialize i from 1? and change the condition to j<=i?

Comment: @Fahad, i must be 0 right? Otherwise we cannot print the first character of the string. Do you mean to initialize j from 0 and change the condition to j<=i. I guess that one should be harmless.

Comment: @jayI was going for initializing i=1.Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

In your `print_repeat` code, you never increment `i` in your `while` loop, which would result in infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

add "i++;" on the end of the while loop.